# iOS SwiftUI: Top trailing gradient triangle

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to create a top trailing triangle filled with a gradient color (pink and yellow) to look exactly like this prototype:

[image]

What I already did is this shape:

```swift
struct Triangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))

        return path
    }
}
```

and I just drop it in the content view like this:

```swift
GeometryReader { geometry in
                   Triangle()
                .fill( LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.yellow.opacity(0.5), Color.pink.opacity(0.5)]),
                                        startPoint: .topTrailing,
                                        endPoint: .bottomLeading
                                    )
                                    
                                )
                       .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 1.65, height: 210)
                       .position(x: geometry.size.width, y: 105)
               }
               .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

but the result is this:

[image]

Any suggestions to achieve a similar prototype is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
adding `.blur(radius: 100)` after the `.fill` modifier will achieve a very close result.

Comment: Did you try adding blur and played around with it?

Comment: where is the pink in your colors?

Comment: Please describe the desired result - it is not practical to look at a screenshot and figure out how it is drawn "exactly". Or, forget about "exact", just describe just the characteristics that you need.

Comment: Also, your code currently produces a triangle on the *trailing* side, not "leading" as the question title suggests. The screenshot showing the output of your code seems to be taken with a RTL layout direction. Please clarify which side you want the triangle.

Comment: @JAHelia "adding `.blur(radius: 100)` after the `.fill` modifier will achieve a very close result", so you got your answer? If not, please make it clear how does the result of adding `blur` differ from your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the gradient is round and splashed vertically, but you can try to mock it with liner gradient as follows:

1. **Add a gradient** properly - the yellow is on the left and pink
   is on the right, i.e. the direction of the gradient has 0 angle
   (actually it something like -pi/6).
2. **Add a mask** from 1 opacity to 0 opacity with the direction you
   used - .topTrailing -> .bottomLeading
3. Play with angles and distances (via `x`, `y` and `location`). Comment `fill` or `mask` to see the exact effect of the opposite modifier, then uncomment back.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TriangleGradientView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(LinearGradient(
                    gradient: Gradient(
                        stops: [
                            .init(color: Color.yellow.opacity(0.3), location: 0),
                            .init(color: Color.pink.opacity(0.4), location: 0.5)
                        ]
                    ),
                    startPoint: .init(x: 0, y: 0),
                    endPoint: .init(x: 1, y: 1)
                ))
                .mask(LinearGradient(
                    gradient: Gradient(
                        stops: [.init(color: .black, location: 0.4),
                                .init(color: .black.opacity(0), location: 0.8)]
                    ),
                    startPoint: .init(x: 0, y: 0),
                    endPoint: .init(x: 0.33, y: 1)
                ))
                .frame(height: 210)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

#Preview {
    TriangleGradientView()
}
```

[image]